# What is the significance for a woman of seeing one's hair parting filled with Vibhuti (sacred ash ) during her marriage in her dreams?

Tags: scripture, shiva, shiva-lingam, dream

What is the significance for a woman of seeing one's hair parting filled with [Vibhuti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibhuti) (sacred ash ) during her marriage in her dreams?

Do any Scriptures discuss the significance of such dreams?

Does the analysis vary depending on whether the woman is married or not?